# Beautiful Soup data repetition

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape Prerequisites from my uni website using beautiful soup, but results are repeating themselfs.

MATH 203 appears once in the given URL but it appears 3 times in my result. I guess it is about `.next_element` method but I couldn't totally fix it.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

class Course:
  def __init__(self, major, code):
    self.major = major
    self.code = code

website = "https://suis.sabanciuniv.edu/prod/sabanci_www.p_get_courses?levl_code=UG&subj_code=CS&crse_numb=210&lang=eng"
result = requests.get(website)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
# print(soup.prettify())
data = soup.table
data = BeautifulSoup(str(data), 'html.parser')
data = data.find("b", string=lambda text:"Pre" in text)
data = data.parent
preqs = list()
# preqs.add(data.contents[1])
while True:
    data = data.next_element
    text = (data.getText())
    if "Core" in text:
        break
    elif (text.strip() != ""):
        if "Prerequisite:"== text.strip():
            continue
        if text.strip()[:3] == "and":
            text = (text.strip()[4:])
            idx = text.find(" ")
            major = text[:idx]
            code = text[idx+1:text.find(" ", idx+1)]
            preqs.append({"major":major, "code":code})
        else:
            # preqs.add(text.strip())
            idx = text.find(" ")
            major = text[:idx]
            code = text[idx+1:text.find(" ", idx+1)]
            preqs.append({"major":major, "code":code})


for preq in preqs:
    print(preq["major"]+preq["code"])
```